# AWS Cognito: Get Access_token from url fragment after successful login (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-cognito

After going through countless documentation, articles, and videos, I am still lost on how I ultimately use AWS Cognito access keys in order to verify a user is logged in (after logging in and moving around the website) and ultimately, signing out.

I was able to set up Cognito user pools through which users are able to create accounts, sign in, etc.
After a user signs in, they are redirected to the url:

```
 https://somedomain.com/callback#id_token=[id_token]&#access_token=[access_token]&#expires=[expires]
```

I cannot access the access_token using python as it is on the client side and not server side (due to being a url fragment). However, from what I understand, I need this access_token in order to use the cognito API for other calls (sign out, etc). How can I extract this access_token fragment from the url? Am I not supposed to access it from the URL but from another source? I appreciate any guidance or feedback as this is my first time using cognito.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?